# JSON - Cannot read property 'viewers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitch

I am trying to get a list of viewers from twitch and it keeps giving me an error even though I am pretty sure I have the right format ...

here is the code and [here is an example on jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZAbD/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/nightblue3/chatters?callback=?", function (data) {
        console.log(data.chatters.viewers); //This should be in the right format based of the json data?!
    });


});
```

Comment: try `data.data.chatters.viewers`. By the way.. I only get _Cannot read property 'viewers' of undefined_

Comment: This error message means that `data.chatters` is undefined and therefore you cannot access the property `viewers`. So basically, your  `data` object is not what you expect it to be. So what you can do is `console.log(data);` to see what `data` really is and what properties it actually has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the variable `data`, but that `data` object has another `data` object inside that contains the `chatters.viewers`, so it should be :

```
$.getJSON("http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/nightblue3/chatters?callback=?", function (data) {
    console.log(data.data.chatters.viewers); //This should be in the right format based of the json data?!
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZAbD/3/)

Comment: Thankyou! That worked, and yeah I do get   Cannot read property 'viewers' of undefined but I put 'x' cause  was trying it with multiple things :)